# Can I have a vigenere cypher decoder ring?

Tags: vigenere

We've all seen tables of characters useful in encoding or decoding a vigenere cypher. Could such a chart be implemented in a decoder ring?

I envision three rings in one. As the user turns the top ring to align a text-character with a key-character on the second ring, the third ring turns to align the cypher-character, and working the other way, turning the third ring to align the cypher-character with the key-character aligns the first ring to the text-character.

Does that exist? If it doesn't, could it? Cuz I want one.

Comment: These sorts of things? https://www.yeggi.com/q/cipher+decoder+ring/